# AWS Lambda - Where to Keep the configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

My system architecture looks like as follows:-

SNS -> AWS Lambda -> Dynamo Db

So, SNS is publishing messages to which AWS Lambda function is the subscriber and then AWS Lambda pushes the data into Dynamo Db. In this, I am doing some transformation of messages in AWS Lambda. For the transformation, I have to fetch some rules from some place. These rules are basically the mapping between fields of the original messages to fields to transformed messages.

```
Eg. 

Say, Original Message looks like below:-
{"id": 1,
"name":"dsadas",
"house":"dsads dsadsa",
"speciality":"asjdsa"
}

and my mapping is something like:-
{"id":"id",
"house":"home",
"speciality":"area"
}
```

So, basically I am saying that id should be mapped to id, house to home and so on.

So, I want to keep this mapping at some places like Dynamo Db or some config service. I do not want to directly keep it in aws lambda code as there is a chance that I might have to change. But keeping it in Dynamo Db will be very costly in terms of latency I think because I will make a call on each message request. So, can anyone suggest, any aws resource which can be used for keeping these configs which is very fast and normally used for keeping configuration.

Comment: One consideration: It sounds like you may not fully understand one implication of Lambda's frequent container reuse.  Declare a global variable (before the handler, the specific mechanism depends on the language of course) and with each invocation, you need to load the config into that variable only if the variable is undefined.  If the variable already has a value, you don't need to load it again, and you will often find it already populated, because the container is being reused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need full flexibility of modifying the mapping, without modifying the Lambda code, you have to rely on S3 or Dynamodb or any other storage service to keep the mappings which also adds latency and cost.

You can also keep a separate mapping.json(or js) and upload the file along with your Lambda code. The drawback is, you need to redeploy the Lambda function for each mapping.json modification.

Another option is to use environment variables, only to keep the attribute mapping key value pairs and the mapping template is constructed inside Lambda using these variables.

You can also use base64 encoding of the mapping template to an environment variable and use it in Lambda.